# How does this PF rule serve in "stopping all probes from outside the network"?

Tags: network-programming, firewall, freebsd

Referring to Section [**29.3.3.3. Managing ICMP** of the FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/firewalls-pf.html), I see the following text with example:

> One solution is to let all ICMP traffic from the local network through
> while stopping all probes from outside the network:
>
> `pass inet proto icmp from $localnet to any keep state`
>
> `pass inet proto icmp from any to $ext_if keep state`

I read this as:
"Pass IPv4 ICMP packets which originate from $localnet to any host/port, and keep the state.
Pass IPv4 ICMP packets which originate from any host/port to $ext_if, and keep the state."

How does this stop probes from outside of the network?  I have limited understanding but it is leading me to believe that the second rule is actually allowing probes from outside of the network.

Is it, and if not, how should I be reading that rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see (and I am most definitely **not** a FreeBSD or PF guy), the base `pf.cfg` that you create in step **29.3.3** includes `block in all`. If I understand correctly, this basically makes the PF filter a default-deny, and only permits traffic which is expressly allowed (using `pass` rules). Therefore, the `pass` rule will permit all **outbound** ICMP packets (and their replies), allow all **inbound** ICMP packets **that have a destination IP of $ext_if only**, and all other ICMP packets will be blocked by the default `block in all`.

This particular setup makes the most sense in a non-NATting gateway, as when NAT is in effect external nodes cannot ping internal nodes whether these rules are enabled or not.

Feel free to correct me if mistaken, as is very possible.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of the $ext_if being bound to a public IP address, as in the case of a web server.  In that case, the rule in 29.3.3 would allow anybody's ICMP packets through which were directed at the $ext_if, meaning probes from outside of the network.  I feel like I'm missing something, though...

Comment: I believe that what it is actually preventing is probing of the internal network, not the host itself. I believe this rule is meant more for a gateway-type system, rather than a host system (eg. web server, mail server).